# How can one apply an itemtemplate to default TabItems?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following TabControl with 2 default tabitems.

```xaml
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="300" Content="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabItem Header="Conexión"><local:ConnectionSettings/></TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Cuestionario"><local:QuestionEditor/></TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

The current xaml doesn't apply the ItemTemplate, for that to happen each tabitem would need to be "naked", like this:

```xaml
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="300" Content="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <!-- The ItemTemplate is only applied if tabitems are not wrapped in TabItem tags -->
    <local:ConnectionSettings/>
    <local:QuestionEditor/>
</TabControl>
```

But if I do that, then I can't specify the header.

I would like for every TabItem to be wrapped in a ScrollViewer (as specified in the ItemTemplate), but at the same be able to specify the header.

Is there a way to apply the ItemTemplate to `<TabItem Header="MyHeader"/>` tags?

Comment: `ItemTemplate` is applied to items inside `ItemsSource`. Adding `TabItem` adds it to `Items` not `ItemsSource`. You **cannot** set `ItemsSource` and `Items` at the same time.

Comment: How do you mean `every TabItem to be wrapped in a ScrollViewer`? TabItem can't be wrapped inside another element, if they do they won't be TabItems and TabControl will not support them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ItemTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateproperty?view=netcore-3.1) is the template to format the [ItemsSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource?view=netcore-3.1) the headers on top of your tab control. [ContentTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.contenttemplate?view=netcore-3.1) is the template to format the content of the tabs. To wrap your defined content to the scroll viewer, just make use of a new content control inside your template. Here is a minimal sample:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <TabItem>
        <Button Content="Button1"/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem>
        <Button Content="Button2"/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```